# How to parse a dataframe column having dynamic records and write it into different columns by maintaining the relation with the table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
cur = snow_connection.cursor()
data = snow_connection.cursor().execute("SELECT x,y,z FROM abc.testing_view2").fetchall()
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.columns = ['x','y','z']
print(df)

temp_col=df.iloc[:,2]
print(temp_col)
for i in range (len(df.iloc[:,0])):
    for j in range(len(df.iloc[:,1])):
        for k in range(len(temp_col)):
            json_dict = str(json.loads(str(k)))
            print(json_dict)
    # accessing values in the dictionary
            portfolio_name = str(json_dict[0])
            portfolio_id = str(json_dict[1])
            for l in range(len(portfolio_name)):
                for m in range(len(portfolio_id)):
    # created a new dictionary with all three columns
                    new_dict = {'name': portfolio_name, 'portfolio_id': portfolio_id,'x': ['X'], 'y': ['Y']}
                    print(new_dict)
                    new_data = []
                    new_data.append(new_dict)
                    new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_data)
```

The problem is column z(which is having json record with name and id) is having dynamic records i.e could contain only one record with name and id and more than 1 too. but it will be mapped with only one x and y. So i have to write this data into multiple rows i.e if column z contains one record then it should write the data into 4 columns x,y ,name and id and if column z contains 2 records then it should write the data and create 2 rows.

I am iterating into this column and writing it into a dictionary to maintain the relation however it is not reading the json dict i created for name and id.

Sample Data:

```
{
  "document_portfolio": "[{\"name\": \"MWP FT Income ICP\", \"portfolio_id\": \"31a01afd-1f69-e617-ade3-d7c1895c4461\"}, {\"name\": \"MWP Tactical ETP IMG\", \"portfolio_id\": \"13281ca6-a9a7-d361-1cf2-07e6fa3e283a\"}]",
  "document_uuid": "28d7ccb1-3f9f-fdd0-c757-6b134a74fdd3",
  "user_id": "00u9vj92B0ZPUMU9b5d5"
}

{
"document_portfolio": "[{\"name\": \"tesying\", \"portfolio_id\": \"59d26651-3484-e7ef-9ece-f7194d7639e0\"}]","document_uuid": "1cf1ca8e-f0e9-844b-11d6-0d05302fb777",
"user_id": "00u5flkeths3G668k5d7"
}
```

Expected output :

```
portfolio_id    name    portfolio_uuid  user_id

31a01afd-1f69-e617-ade3-d7c1895c4461    MWP FT Income ICP   28d7ccb1-3f9f-fdd0-c757-6b134a74fdd3    00u9vj92B0ZPUMU9b5d5

13281ca6-a9a7-d361-1cf2-07e6fa3e283a    MWP Tactical ETP IMG    28d7ccb1-3f9f-fdd0-c757-6b134a74fdd3    00u9vj92B0ZPUMU9b5d5
```

Sample Snowflake logic:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW port_test_vw AS
    SELECT 
      LATERAL FLATTEN(PARSE_JSON(data:document_portfolio):portfolio) flattened,
flattened:name::string AS portfolio_name,
flattened:portfolio_id::string AS portfolio_id,
FROM XYZ;
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided some sample data and expected output.  This seems like something that might be easier to solve with straight Snowflake SQL, but it is hard to tell based on your question.

Comment: Use `pd.read_json` instead of `json.loads`

Comment: @MikeWalton .... I have added sample data .... I searched the snowflake documentation. Tried using Flatten method but again it didnt worked.

Comment: Thanks @jqurious ... so i changed the logic a bit and I am able to parse the records in the dynamic data column ... however it is only reading first record but not able to iterate if there are more than one record. Can someone point out the mistake here?

Comment: This could be done in a single Snowflake query using LATERAL FLATTEN, rather than pulling the data into python and iterating over the recordset.

Comment: @MikeWalton .... I already tried this solution but I am getting error with the syntax. Tried UNNEST method too.

Comment: Your syntax for lateral flatten was not correct.  I've put an answer below for you, if interested.

Comment: Thanks @MikeWalton.... I am able to create view using this syntax . however data is not getting loaded. I am adding the logic here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW document_testing_view222 
AS SELECT 
data:document_portfolio::STRING AS document_portfolio,
doc_port.value:name::string AS portfolio_name,
doc_port.value:portfolio_id::string AS portfolio_id 
FROM pcs.document, 
lateral flatten(input=>PARSE_JSON(data:document_portfolio):document_portfolio) doc_port;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the above issue. Hope if someone is also having you can reuse this logic:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.columns = ['DOCUMENT_ID', 'DOCUMENT_UUID', 'USER_ID', 'DOCUMENT_PORTFOLIO'] 
for row in data:
    document_id = row[0] 
    document_uuid = row[1] 
    user_id = row[2] 
    json_dict = row[3]
    portfolio_data = json.loads(json_dict)
    for item in portfolio_data:
        portfolio_name = item['name'] 
        portfolio_id = item['portfolio_id'] 
        new_row = {'DOCUMENT_ID': document_id, 'DOCUMENT_UUID': document_uuid, 'USER_ID': user_id, 'PORTFOLIO_NAME': portfolio_name, 'PORTFOLIO_ID': portfolio_id}
        df = df.append(new_row, ignore_index=True) 
        #print(df)
        table_name = 'XYZ' 
        with snow_connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(f"CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE {table_name}(DOCUMENT_ID INT,DOCUMENT_UUID TEXT,USER_ID TEXT,PORTFOLIO_NAME TEXT,PORTFOLIO_ID TEXT)") 
df.to_sql(table_name, snow_connection, index=False, if_exists='append')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Snowflake SQL syntax for you:

```
with x as (
select parse_json('{
  "document_portfolio": [{"name": "MWP FT Income ICP", "portfolio_id": "31a01afd-1f69-e617-ade3-d7c1895c4461"}, {"name": "MWP Tactical ETP IMG", "portfolio_id": "13281ca6-a9a7-d361-1cf2-07e6fa3e283a"}],
  "document_uuid": "28d7ccb1-3f9f-fdd0-c757-6b134a74fdd3",
  "user_id": "00u9vj92B0ZPUMU9b5d5"
}')::variant as var
)
SELECT y.value:name::string AS portfolio_name,
       y.value:portfolio_id::string AS portfolio_id
FROM x,
lateral flatten(input=>var:document_portfolio) y;
```